# Declaration in C considered definition in C++

Tags: python, c++, c, python-c-api

I am working on an open-source C file containing the following declaration

```
static PyTypeObject Bitarraytype;
```

followed later by the definition

```
static PyTypeObject Bitarraytype = {
    /* A bunch of stuff */ 
};
```

I am porting this code to C++ (`-std=C++2a`), however the above declaration and definition is no longer allowed, as it claims `error: redefinition of 'Bitarraytype'`

I'm not sure what's causing this, as the first block above is only a declaration from my understanding. Why doesn't this work in C++ and how can I get around it?

Comment: For the last question (getting around it), is there a reason you cannot remove the "declaration"? (That just seems to me like the first workaround to try.)

Comment: Essentially a lot of the code in-between relies on the existence of the type, and the definitions of the type relies on the code in-between. I'm not the author of the code, and would like to change as little as possible to make the merge request easy.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration you show is actually a *tentative definition* in C.  C++ doesn't have that, so you get a multiple definition error.

The declaration should be marked `extern` to mark it is as declaration:

```
extern PyTypeObject Bitarraytype;
```

You'll also need to remove the `static` keyword, as the two are incompatible.

Comment: Marking it as `extern` throws the new error 
`error: cannot combine with previous 'extern' declaration specifier`. Removing the `static` keyword resolves the error, though.

Comment: Assuming the declarations are a file scope, remove the `static` keyword.

Comment: Well they were file scope, but with `extern` I would think they are global scope. It is also my understanding that all of the definitions in a C/C++ extension of Python should be `static`

Comment: @walnut I think you can use anonymous namespaces to make that work: [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69550f76893953a8)

Comment: Don't know how I missed that.   Edited.